# Apex JSON: Getting error - Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, json, visuaforce

I am getting error: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!doFetchCOVIDInfo}' in component  in page covid19page: Class.COVID19Manager.doFetchCOVIDInfo:

Aim: I am trying to fetch all the Covid19 cases via API ([here](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/4074074/SzS7Pkup?version=latest)) and display(after parsing the returned JSON) after a button click.

Following is the COVID19Manager Class:

```
public class COVID19Manager{

   public static list<WrapperCOVID19Info> covid19{get;set;}
   public COVID19Manager(){
       System.debug('###Constructor called!!!!!!!!');
       covid19 = new list<WrapperCOVID19Info>();
   }


    public class WrapperCOVID19Info{
        public string country{get;set;}
        public string country_abbreviation{get;set;}
        public string total_cases{get;set;}
        public string new_cases{get;set;}
        public string total_deaths{get;set;}
        public string new_deaths{get;set;}
        public string total_recovered{get;set;}
        public string active_cases{get;set;}
        public string serious_critical{get;set;}
        public string cases_per_mill_pop{get;set;}
        public string flag{get;set;}

    }

    public void doFetchCOVIDInfo(){


        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint('https://corona-virus-stats.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cases/countries-search');
        res = h.send(req);
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());

        while (parser.nextToken() != null){
             if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                 while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                      if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {
                          WrapperCOVID19Info covidCase = new WrapperCOVID19Info();
                          covidCase = (WrapperCOVID19Info)parser.readValueAs(WrapperCOVID19Info.class);
                              if(string.isNotBlank(covidCase.Country)){
                              covid19.add(covidCase);
                              }
                      }
                 }   
             }
         }

      system.debug(covid19.size());  
    }//END of method

}//END of Class
```

This list is then displayed using vf page below:

```
<apex:page Controller="COVID19Manager" >
<apex:form >
<apex:commandButton value="Get List" action="{!doFetchCOVIDInfo}"/>

     <apex:pageBlock title="Covid19List">
             <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!covid19}" var="c">
                 <apex:column value="{!c.country}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!c.country_abbreviation}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!c.total_cases}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!c.new_cases}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!c.total_deaths}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!c.new_deaths}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!c.total_recovered}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!c.active_cases}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!c.serious_critical}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!c.cases_per_mill_pop}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!c.flag}"/>   
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this error... 
Thanks

Comment: I think your doFetchCOVIDInfo needs to return a PageReference type and you can return null

Comment: @ScottMorrison i think page reference is only required when we want to jump to other VF page when something is clicked, and method takes you to new VF page. In this case, i am trying to display a List object on click of a button.

Comment: Which line in the method is throwing the error?

Comment: Last line of the loop, covid19.add(covidCase)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static list<WrapperCOVID19Info> covid19{get;set;}
```

This does not create an instance of a collection of `WrapperCOVID19Info`. You must either create the instance in the `get;` or simply check the null value in `doFetchCOVIDInfo`.

```
public List<WrapperCOVID19Info> covid19 {
    get {
        if (covid19 == null) {
            //covid19 = new List<WrapperCOVID19Info>();
        }
        return covid19;
    }
}
```

or

```
...
if(string.isNotBlank(covidCase.Country)){
    if (covid19 == null) covid19 = new List<WrapperCOVID19Info>();
    covid19.add(covidCase);
}
...
```

Comment: `covidWrapper = null` should be `covidWrapper == null`

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks. I do like to rename the variables while analysing the code blocks to make it easier for my own reference!!

Comment: That worked, thanks @TSmith and sfdcfox